# Data source filtering for a graph

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, graph, datasource

I have a table that looks like this:

```
id | group | time_stamp | value
---|-------|------------|------
01 | 1     | 02:30      | 8
02 | 2     | 03:00      | 9
03 | 2     | 03:00      | 14
04 | 1     | 03:30      | 10
05 | 2     | 04:00      | 12
```

I want to display the values of group 1 in a line graph. I created a data source and a graph. The XValueMember is a `time_stamp` and the YValueMember of the series of the graph is a `value`. Now the graph is based on all records, which I completely understand. But how do I select only the records of a certain group? I want to make a button to toggle the groups.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: It would help if you show the code you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can transform the data into the form you want by doing something like the following.

```
var lineGraphs = data
    .GroupBy(x => x.group)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Group = g.Key,
        Points = g
            .Select(x => new { X = x.time_stamp, Y = x.value })
            .OrderBy(p => p.X)
            .ToList()
    })
    .ToList();
```

The namespace `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization` then has interactive graph controls that will give you basic functionality for displaying data like this.